# How can I draw a porous particle?

Tags: mesh, particles

I want to know how to model a porous particle that has a solid or hollow inner space. I want to know how to control the surface thickness in case of the hollow particle.

I found a tutorial, *[Porous Particle in 3D Graphics –Let’s Shade 3D #006](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqgqO41_1u4)*, but it's made by another software.

The second question is: How can I cut a triangle from the particle to illustrate what is inside?

Examples of hollow, solid, porous particle and a cut particle.

[image: Example of porous particle and cutaway view of a particle]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Hey guys ... you provoke me :)

No deformations on surface. No glitches in animation with booleans.*

---

### Shape 01

- add *Icosphere*
- *Bevel* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> Vertices <kbd>V</kbd>
- *Delete* <kbd>X</kbd> newly generated faces

[image]

Modifiers:

- *Subdivision* - Level 2
- *Cast* – Sphere, Factor 1 (to get perfect sphere shape)
- *Solidify* for thickness
- *Boolean* - to cut quarter by another object like a Cube

[image]

Notes: Switch to **Edge or Face select mode** before bevelling so newly generated faces stay selected. For boolean use **Exact** solver. Smooth shading is used with enabled under *Properties Editor > Data Properties > Normals >* **Auto Smooth**.

---

If you need more dense holes just increase **Subdivision to 3** in step one (add Icosphere) in Properties panel (left-bottom in View3D editor).

[image]

[image]

---

### Shape 02

For version with vertical holes it is a bit more difficult...

- Add Plane, Subdivide <kbd>W</kbd> a few times and as before ...
- *Bevel* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> Vertices <kbd>V</kbd>
- *Delete* <kbd>X</kbd> newly generated faces

[image]

- Add *Sphere*
- Add *Shrinkwrap* modifier to *Plane* with *Wrap method > Project*, *Target > Sphere* and *Apply* modifier

[image]

- At a bottom delete corners, select border vertices and search for *To Sphere* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> set <kbd>1</kbd> to get edge circular. Alternatively you can add one extra Loop cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Select holes by Loop Select <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> click on edge in Edge select mode (not Vertex select mode) each hole, Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> a bit in Z axis <kbd>Z</kbd>, Extrude again in Z much more, Scale in Z to zero and move vertices to Z Loc zero
- Create a Vertex Group from outer surface (without tubes)

Modifiers

- Subdivision - Level 2 (to keep holes sharp - exclude edges by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> press 1)
- Cast - Sphere, Factor 1, Radius 1.02, set Vertex Group of outer vertices (you created before) to let modifier affect sphere without tubes
- Mirror - only in Z

[image]

- Boolean - use a Cube to cut

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sweet  - if only booleans worked that well, one can dream...

Comment: Booleans would work if your primitive wasnt a approximation fo something in the first place. Its really hard t get a good exact result of something that is not exact.

Comment: It is a little advanced. I am in the first step, i can not make the plane has vertices inside unless i use grid 7X7 to do look like yours.
But the problem shrinkwrap doesn't come well as yours.

Comment: Grid is fine too. Shrinkwrap - have you switched wrap method to Project? If issue persist check my blend (Plane_01 is in this state) or share your file.

Comment: Yes it worked with wrap method project. Then i was able to delete the vertices on the corner. But next, the holes can not be selected to be extruded. how to extrude ?
i don't see how to upload my file !

Comment: Answer edited ... and I will have to edit again there is a Vertex group used in Cast modifier to affect only outer surface and not extruded holes. Check my blend.

Answer (score 7):

1. Create icosphere + cube
2. add subdivision modifier to icosphere
3. add boolean modifier to icosphere -> object: cube

[image]

4. select icosphere and enter edit mode with TAB

[image]

5. press CTRL-B to bevel and bevel like this:

[image]

6. change to face select
7. select one circle face

[image]

8. select->select similar -> polygon sides

[image]

then you will get:

[image]

9. Tap X -> Faces

[image]

10. press TAB
11. Shade smooth

[image]

12. select the cube and change viewport display to bounds

[image]

13. move the cube over the sphere as you need it

Result:

[image]

[image]

of course you can give it a solidify modifier, as vklidu said, looks even a bit better:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice :). Reminds me of those image-based web tutorials pre-Youtube. After 150 images you feel like you earned the knowledge :).

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!!

Comment: For better topology use Bevel Vertices Only (Ctrl+B and V). And you can skip selection process if you switch to Edge or Face selection mode that let newly generated faces selected after Bevel. https://imgur.com/ernOXtT To add thickess use Solidify modifier ...

Comment: Beveled Vertices also didn't result as perfect sphere so I add Cast modifier (Sphere, Factor 1). Triangulation is used for older version of Boolean (without Exact) ... https://imgur.com/A4UPtkP

Comment: At last! A place for you to use that deleted answer of yours :D

Comment: Nope - it was a new one. ;) But that you can remember my deleted answers shows your unbelievable memory...and brain! ;)

Comment: Mr Chris, I don't know how to thank you. You let me achieve my dream, a difficult dream. Thank you so much so much.

Comment: @MajdiAl-Amili : Glad I could help. Please check the checkmark left to my answer, if it is helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you  vklidu, I realized how to increase the thickness now, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Chris your sphere is not still sphere (holes generates like crater shapes) that is why I used Cast modifier. Also you can't use second Subsurf after Solidify only before ... it subsurfs holes edges ... and for that you unchecked "Rim Fill" in solidify (I guess) that results as two separate layers instead of thickness ... right :) Modifier order https://imgur.com/A4UPtkP

Answer (score 5):

Let's try with, hated for good reasons, boolean workflow, mainly because I think the tutorial you linked uses booleans. Though there the holes aren't distributed evenly:

[image]

The above could be achieved by making a cone, and adding two array modifiers, but we can do better, like Chris, so let's try but with boolean modifier.

The advantage of boolean is that you don't have to go through a puzzle on proper topology, so this solution should be more versatile (e.g. when you want to replace the cones with cylinders as on one of your reference images). The disadvantages are, however, plenty:

- the resulting topology may be very heavy (a lot of triangles)
- booleans are often buggy and cause issues with animations due to inconsistency
- there are also problems with smooth shading and resolving them can be quite tricky (normal data transfer from the original uncut sphere)

Add an *Ico Sphere* (because that generates equally spaced triangles), then add a cone, edit it, using *Increment Snapping* [image] (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or click the magnet button) move the cone so that the tip is at the world (sphere) center. I also move the base up because I find it more natural to look an an object from the top, but that's just my preference. Then I rotate the cone to make it roughly fit a triangle (keep in mind in this situation you have to rotate along green Y axis, not red X axis, due to how the triangles are distributed). If you readjust the distance of the base of the cone to the center, remember to use <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> but in **local** coordinate space, ignoring the rotation of the object. [image]

[image] [image]

Let's name this cone `Cone.A`, and duplicate it, and name the duplicate `Cone.B`, let's also <kbd>H</kbd>ide `Cone.B` for now. Likewise rename the Ico Sphere to `Ico.A`, and create a duplicate `Ico.B`, hide the latter.

Select `Cone.A`, then `Ico.A`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>.

Edit the `Ico.A`, select the triangle overlapped by the cone, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>:

[image]

Now in object mode, with the `Cone.A` selected, press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for `Set origin to 3D cursor`. In <kbd>N</kbd>umbers panel, clear (set to 0) cone's rotation as well as location, so it's inside the sphere, then with `Ico.A` selected, change its instancing to *Faces*:

[image]

And we got the cones:

[image]

Though there's still some room for additional cones - exactly where the Ico Sphere's vertices are... So let's hide the `Ico.A` and `Cone.A`, unhide the `Ico.B`, Edit the mesh, select everything, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for bevel, scroll down (mouse wheel) for minimum number of edges, <kbd>C</kbd> to clamp, and move your mouse to maximize the bevel like so:

[image]

<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, increase the range until you remove all small faces:

[image]

Adjust `Cone.B` to the top face of `Ico.B` just was done with `A` variant. Don't resize the cone, though. Result:

[image]

I'd advise hiding both sphere, going into edit mode of each cone, hiding everything except the base face, then in object mode unhiding everything, selecting both cones, going to edit mode, and then scaling the bases so they have satisfying size:

[image]

Select `Cone.A`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> (Make instances real), <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click one of the cones to activate it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join those cones into a single mesh/object. <kbd>H</kbd> to hide it. Repeat for `Cone.B`. Remove the rest. Unhide the cones, select both, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them. Now you have the equivalent of the first screenshot in this post.

You can now create a "proper" sphere to your liking, e.g. UV sphere. You can add another sphere to cut the insides of the main sphere, you can add a cube to cut a fragment of the resulting shape... Once you're done, Hide the cones, as well as other objects you use for cutting (or change their display to *bounds*, as I did for the inner sphere and the cube) and add boolean modifiers like so (before doing so better save your project :D):

[image]

And here's an underperforming animation, notice the bugs...

[image]

Comment: This can really enrich the the imagination and understanding, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Markus, although you got an upvote from me for you answer - it looks like that some beginners have difficulties to reproduce it and so someone asks for a video about it...maybe you want to help...

Comment: @Chris I see, Edu39 had some problems. I'll think of a way how to clear the answer, though ideally he would write here and we could create a chat for him.

Comment: thank you! I have no idea how to create that chat... :D

Comment: @Chris I know how - just spam here until the option appears ;) but let's wait and see if Edu39 even comes here.

Comment: He wrote me that he opened a new question…

Comment: @Chris yes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/230427/60486