# 3D porous nanoparticle. How can I draw one?

Tags: modeling, materials, particles, topology, parent

[image]

Hi!.

I would like to draw something similar to this porous Nanoparticle. The inside of each hole needs to be "solid" and each of them kind of spherical shaped, similar to a golf ball.

It would great to have it.

There is another post about 3D porous nanoparticles, but as a I am a beginner, it would be nice to have a full step-by-step tutorial. Including keys, etc...

Thank you in advance.

Edit: They shut this question apparently because 7 years ago there was a similar post...well, the suggested post do not show how to create holes in a solid sphere. The examples showed an internal void in the sphere, like a casing. I would like to produce "solid" holes

So apparently I am capable of creating a golf ball, XD...

[image]

nothing really similar to the picture posted above. That's why I think it would be great to have a more detailed explanation about the last example [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227470/how-can-i-draw-a-porous-particle) posted

Comment: I saw this exact question in Hot questions yesterday, but can't get my hand on it...

Comment: maybe this will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196461/trying-to-get-even-spaced-dimples-on-a-sphere-golf-ball

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for something like the last example of this post. Without the triangular cut, just the full sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227470/how-can-i-draw-a-porous-particle

Comment: Why wouldn't the vklidu's method work? It seems better in every way - is there some particular characteristic of hole spacing that my answer satisfies, and his doesn't?

Comment: vklidu's method works fine as well, just his seems to create an internal void (like a thick skin or a rind, I do not know the correct word in english). Anyways, I am a beginner, it would be very helpful to have like a video tutorial or a really step-by-step guide (made for dummies, XD)

Comment: To the moderator: My question is similar but no the same as the suggested post. I am asking how to produce "solid" holes in a sphere, not holes in a sphere with an internal void!

Comment: Using VKlidu's technique you can adequately achieve your goal. At the very step one, rather than delete the faces with `X` just extrude them inwards instead. You'll end with up "capped holes" rather than a shell.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that, @Duarte Farrajota Ramos