# How do you I anchor the tip of the cone to the center of this sphere?

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials, 3d-view, image

I am trying to follow the last example of this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227470/how-can-i-draw-a-porous-particle), but I do not know how to anchor the tip of the cone to the center of the sphere. Whenever I rote the cone, it rotates through its mass center instead of the center of the sphere

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just choose [**3D Cursor**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html) for the pivot point. This uses the cursor which is in the center of the sphere.

[image: pivot point selections]

*Active Element* should also work but in *Object* mode only. Because you're in *Edit* mode and have selected a face so it does *not* use the object's origin (orange dot) but the face.

Comment: That's great really. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to rotate round the tip, select the vertex at the tip rather than the bottom face!

Comment: If that "works great", please consider to accept the answer @Edu39 How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Done, sorry about that.