# How can I create the holes in a sphere, "cone shaped"?

Tags: modeling, python, rendering, animation, mesh

So, I managed to produce a sphere sorrounded by cones, like this

[image]

The idea is to create a porous particle showing holes with the shape of those cones (exluding them like in this image).

[image]

I have already joined all the cones using Control+J, the next step should be something like this option (typically used in other 2D Graphic Design Software) [image]

Thanks!

Comment: what you're looking for is the Boolean modifier, I don't know if it will give a good result though as the topology will be messy

Comment: I must say that I am really a beginner in Blender. When I selected both the sphere and the joined cones, then I do boolean modifier and apply it says "modifier is disable skipping apply"

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I think I did it. Could you confirm it?

Comment: Is it ok?. It's the first time I use this sharing thing. 
https://pasteall.org/blend/5f694d13c7c8490db293f80d15033578

Comment: Sure the above result has been answered before, re making model, via screw &  inset on UV sphere.... maybe for golfball dimples. If scripting would not use method above either.

Comment: The golfball example do not produce the type of hole I want.

Comment: btw, how did you make the cones rotate all around the sphere?

Comment: @moonboots , not sure if this is what you exactly need. Check it out, and let me know https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230640/how-do-you-i-anchor-the-tip-of-the-cone-to-the-center-of-this-sphere

Comment: my question is how did you create all your cones here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8csVS.jpg ... did you rotate them manually?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I had to do it manually, which took me like 5-10 minutes...Not the most efficient way for sure

Comment: @Edu39 so what method did you choose (if this is explanable in few words), because it doesn't seem obvious to keep something rather regular all around

Comment: Ok, so at first I tried the cone thing using the boolean modifier as you suggested me (spreading the cones by hand). However it did not work very well as I could not produce a decent and smoothed sphere in the end. Then, I changed to the second method suggested by @Robin Betts which worked fine for me.

Comment: yes, Robin's method is the simplest, but my question was how did you create all your cones all around the sphere  ;)  I wonder how you were able to make them correctly placed

Comment: Sorry, now I understand. Really, I did it by hand!. I was patience enough (and probably lucky) to place all of them quite at the same distance. But I can asure you I did it by hand. My Blender skills are really really limited (have a look at my questions, XD), but I really needed it done

Comment: oh ok, I thought you calculated the rotation angles and everything and it made me scratch my head how to do it  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your sphere, go into the *Modifiers* panel, give your sphere a *Boolean* modifier with the cone object as *Object*, choose the *Difference* option, duplicate both the sphere and the cone object to keep a copy somewhere, apply the modifier (select the modifier, keep your mouse over the modifier and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and it will work (delete the cones otherwise you'll think it hasn't worked):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i got an error message in red color: "modifier is disable, skipping apply"

Comment: I think I need to have selected, in the object box, the "icosphere" ...which is now currently empty, but it does not appear when I click on the same box

Comment: yes you need to select the cone object, not sure why you can't

Comment: I will keep trying, but anyways I accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Maybe better not to use a Boolean?

1. Enable the shipped add-on: *Geodesic Domes* (There are other ways, but this is quick.)
2. Create your dome:

[image]

3. With <kbd>I</kbd> Inset, ('Individual' checked in its <kbd>F9</kbd> Adjust Last Operation panel,)  inset all its faces.

[image]

4. Set your Pivot to 3D Cursor, and ensure the cursor is at the center of your dome. (It probably hasn't moved since the dome's creation)
5. <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the still-selected inset faces, and right-click to drop the extrusion in place.
6. <kbd>S</kbd> scale the faces toward the centre of the sphere.
7. Assign *Bevel* and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers

[image]

You may wish to treat pentagonal faces differently.. you can select them with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, and select similar, by number of edges.

Comment: Thanks for this. However I do not want a void inside the sphere, I think I will give it a try anyways

Comment: @Edu39 You could Alt E  > extrude the faces inwards along their normals, instead of deleting and solidifying

Comment: you can extrude inwards as Robin says and scale down in order to give each hole a cone shape (you need to choose Pivot Point > Individual Origins), then merge by distance

Comment: @moonboots Ahh, of course! Extrusion doesn't scale. Thanks! Another option: E extrude, right-click to drop, S to scale towards 3D cursor at center of dome.Will edit answer.

Comment: @Edu39 Answer edited to your requirements.

Comment: @Robin Betts, that's really cool, I'll definitely try tomorrow. This is exactly what I was trying to do, but probably i will take me some time. Thanks a lot for the help, people

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I know that wasn't asked, but I just love *Geometry Nodes* :D

An Ico-Sphere is a good starting point here.

The node `Dual Mesh` converts points into faces (and vice versa), which gives you the basic shape.

You can then extrude and scale these faces to get the desired mesh without boolean operations.

The nice thing about this solution is that it is 100% procedural and you can change the parameters at any time.

[image]

And here is another variant with sharp edges:

[image]

[image]

Comment: .. and no pentagons..

Comment: @RobinBetts ...there are a few, but well hidden ;-) I am not sure if they can be avoided with this shape as a base...

Comment: @RobinBetts But the cool thing about it: if you have a basic shape without pentagons, just plug it in, because those are geometry nodes. ...But what I'm telling you, you're a pro. ;-)