# Extruding faces goes wrong when creating holes in a sphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude, origin, axis

I want to draw a porous sphere following @Robin Betts' cool [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230772/how-can-i-create-the-holes-in-a-sphere-cone-shaped) (Geodesic Domes); after succesfully doing the "inset faces" I want to extrude them all inside the sphere, so that I have the final holes.
Any idea why the extruding is moving aparently along one single axis (see here) instead of moving through the three coordinates, inside?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi! the answer says: ' extrude the still-selected inset faces, **and right-click to drop the extrusion in place** ' Extrusion in Blender is a 2-step process.. the extrusion, and then the move. You can extrude without moving, with a right click ( a cause of a lot of errors, when folks don't realise the new faces are still there). E. Right Click. S. @moonboots' way is  clearer,  for folks who haven't yet developed shortcut habits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** so I've just realized that all your cones are supposed to converge towards the same point, in that case, as Robin says, you can just press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude then press *Enter* right away, and scale down with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. When all your cone tips are on the same point, merge by distance with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>

A simple *Extrude* will extrude along the Z local axis of the selected faces. Instead use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals* so that each axis of each face is taken into account. Then if you want to scale down each face in order to create cones, activate *Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins*:

[image]

Then when the faces are small enough, merge by distance with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot @moonboots

Comment: Cheers, too :)  The answer actually recommended right-clicking to drop the extrusion, and then scale.. but the 2-step extrusion must be the cause of dozens of Q's here, when folks think they have cancelled the extrusion, not just the move, with a right-click.

Comment: ok I've just realized that all the cones were converging towards the same point ;)

Comment: btw, in the original question, how did he make the cones rotate all around the sphere?