# Increasing the number of faces in Geodesic object

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, faces, subdivision-surface

I am not capable of reproducing such a great amount of faces as [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230772/how-can-i-create-the-holes-in-a-sphere-cone-shaped), or depicted in the image below

[image]

actually my number of preset faces are quite low (as you can see here).

[image]

The solution might be easy, but I'm still learning blender

Thanks

Comment: Increase the Frequency?

Comment: you also have icospheres that you can bevel, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196461/trying-to-get-even-spaced-dimples-on-a-sphere-golf-ball

Comment: I rather use the geodesic domes following @Robin Betts' advice. Anyways I will give it a try to your link, thanks

Comment: My bad.. I should have included that setting in the illustration. Otherwise, why illustrate? Dooooh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just increase the frequency. So you will get these results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris

Comment: You are welcome