# cone shaped holes in a sphere

Tags: modeling, add-on

recently I met the same question as @Edu39 from this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230772/how-can-i-create-the-holes-in-a-sphere-cone-shaped?noredirect=1&lq=1), I saw a very helpful answer from @Robin Betts as the image shown below, I was wondering how we can download the add-ons that he mentioned? Looking forward to your kindly help! Thank you in advance.
Geodesic Domes add-on
[image]
[image: the model that Robin created]

Comment: The Geodesic Domes addon is already shipped with Blender. Go to Edit Preferences > Addons tab and start typing 'geodesic' into the search field. Put a checkmark beside the 'Add Mesh: Geodesic Domes' entry and you'll then find an extra entry for it at the bottom of the Add > Mesh menu.

Comment: Hi, @wenqiang xiang !   Maybe a language issue..  the key word is 'shipped'. You'll see it in quite a few answers :)